# How to implement React in a jQuery-based webapp?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've been studying React and now I want to try implementing it on some pages only,
as a proof-of-concept to my supervisor at work. How do I do that using old-school
script tags, instead of imports?

I've been able to use the in-browser babel transpiler

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
      ReactDOM.render(
        <div>Hello world!!</div>,
        document.getElementById("output")
      );
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This works, but how do I create react components here? Creating a class that extends Component will throw an undefined error. How do I do `import React, {Component} from 'react';` using this method? And how do I use components in external jsx files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not?

```
<script type="text/babel">
  // Define children components here

  class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (<div>Hello world</div>)
    }
  }

  ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById("output")
  );
</script>
```

**UPD**

For a few components, just write down children components before parent one (look at comment in my code). If you have a lot of components, start to use builders like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)

Comment: Oh okay it works, I just needed to use React.Component. How about including external component jsx files?